# Kubernetes: Cannot convert int64 to string. Kubernetes fails to interpret integer value in helmchart values.yaml file

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl, amazon-eks, spinnaker

I have a `values.yaml` file in which I have given `spring_datasource_hikari_maximum_pool_size: "10"`

In `deployment yaml` I have used this value as

```
 - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_HIKARI_MAXIMUM-POOL-SIZE
    value: {{ .Values.spring_datasource_hikari_maximum_pool_size }}
```

However, when used inside the `deployment.yaml` file it fails with the below error.

```
Deploy failed: The request is invalid: patch: Invalid value: "map[metadata:map[annotations:map[kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:{"apiVersion":"apps/v1","kind":"Deployment","metadata":{"annotations":
{
(helm values etc)
`{"name":"SPRING_DATASOURCE_HIKARI_MAXIMUM-POOL-SIZE","value":10}]` **(this is the incorrect value)** 
}
cannot convert int64 to string
```

What is the correct format of using an integer value from `values.yaml` file in a `deployment.yaml` file?

I have also tried multiple combinations with quotes "" but nothing seems to be working.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: just double-quote your value. Dealing with numeric values (env vars, args, resources allocation) => yaml to json conversion would cast those as integers, rather than strings..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by using **double quotes** on the `value` itself in `deployment.yaml` file

```
- name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_HIKARI_MAXIMUM-POOL-SIZE
  value: "{{ .Values.spring_datasource_hikari_maximum_pool_size }}"
```

Since this was a **production instance** I could not check with @David Maze and Vit's solution.

**Edit:**

Tried with `quote` option and it worked too.

```
 - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_HIKARI_MAXIMUMPOOLSIZE 
   value: {{ quote .Values.spring_datasource_hikari_maximum_pool_size }}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check solutions from [Helm Environment Variables with Booleans and Integers](https://www.shyam.tech/2018/helm-boolean/)

> We can use `!!str` to convert the output to a string, Alternatively we
> can also use a undefined `!!` and get the same behaviour giving later
> developers nice hints of what we intended `!!booleanEnv` or `!!integerEnv`
> will cast the values to string (or even just `!!boolean`)

```
- name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_HIKARI_MAXIMUM-POOL-SIZE
    value: !!integerEnv {{ .Values.spring_datasource_hikari_maximum_pool_size }}
- name: FAVORITE_DRINK
    value: !!stringEnv {{ .Values.favoriteDrink }}
- name: TAKES_SUGAR
    value: !!booleanEnv {{ .Values.takesSugar }}
```

Answer (score 3):

YAML values have types, and the standard rule is to consider a string of digits like `10` to be a number.  In the Kubernetes YAML format, though, the names and values of environment variables have to be strings.

The easiest way to do this is to use the Helm (Sprig) [`quote`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#quote-and-squote) function, which will wrap its parameter in double quotes:

```yaml
- name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_HIKARI_MAXIMUMPOOLSIZE
  value: {{ quote .Values.spring_datasource_hikari_maximum_pool_size }}
{{/*        ^^^^^                                                  */}}
```

`quote` isn't especially intelligent; it's the same as `value: "{{ .Values...}}"`.  There's a similar `squote` that would wrap the value in single quotes.

If you wanted a really robust solution, you could use [`print`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#print) to convert an arbitrary value to a string, then the lightly-documented [`toJson`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#type-conversion-functions) function to convert that to JSON.  By design, valid JSON is valid YAML, and "converting a string to JSON" will mean double-quoting it and otherwise escaping it as needed.

```yaml
value: {{ .Values...pool_size | print | toJson }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. 

I was able to use quotes ("") in the deployment.yaml file like 

value: "{{ .Values.spring_datasource_hikari_maximum_pool_size }}"

Although I didn't think this would work as I thought it will take the literal value inside the quotes. 

However, it worked like a charm, Thanks again @David Maze